# Finding 3D coordinate by using triangulation

Tags: image, geometry, triangulation

I am going to find the real 3D coordinate of a target point in an image with respect to world coordinate system. It is supposed that the XY world coordinate plane is attached to the target plane in parallel and the Z world coordinate axis is perpendicular to the target plane. I also use the stereo camera system to record the image data. Also I have done the stereo camera calibration and rectified images through a stereo rectification process by using the calibration results. Then I utilized the bellow formulas to determine the 3d coordinate of the target points with respect to camera coordinate system: Z=Bf/(Xr-Xl), Y= uZ/f, X=vZ/f

[image]

But these coordinates are with respect to camera coordinate system. If I want to convert these 3d coordinates to the 3d world coordinate system that I have described above, what shall I do to perform this job?

Comment: Any images you could point to?  I know  you can't add them directly until your reputation is higher, but if you can put some on the web somewhere one of us can add them for you.

Comment: Thank you Codie for your kind answer. I appreciate for your helps. If you give me your email, I will send it to you directly. If you recommend any other way let me know. thank you.

Comment: Codie,  you can access the file through this link: http://u.163.com/8Z7dlpex, there is also a password: FBR7ERXB, the name of file is photo. thanks.

Comment: I've added it as promised, but it wasn't really what I was looking for, I was hoping you would diagram your view geometry.

Comment: Codie, Thank you very much for your kind helps. Actually, this picture was for my first question called "detecting circle in an image". But as for the question about triangulation, I have again attached an images in the following link:   http://u.163.com/67Ml6UIs , password: hHQmsSvz.     I hope it would make my question more clear. I will appreciate if you could put this pictures for triangulation question. In this picture, I specified the global coordinate system to which the camera frame should be transferred. thank you.

Comment: There you go, that one makes more sense :-)  But I STILL think you need a diagram that shows Bf, Xr, Xl, uZ, vZ, and f!

Comment: Codie, thanks again for our helps, Actually, I have got these parameters you have mentioned from camera calibration. B= 93.2 mm, f=1404 pixel, for the circle which is attached to world coordinate system, xl= 453 pixel, xr= 374, z=1.67 m, u and v with respect to left camera frame (lens center is considered as the origin) are: u= -174 pixels, v= 106.5. I hope this information will be helpful for solving this problem.

Comment: Codie, if you also need the rectified right and left images, I can put them somewhere for you to take it.